# Организация задержки запроса при вводе данных в input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Стоит задача организовать задержку запроса при вводе текста в input для минимизации отправки запросов на сервер. Написал такой код:

```
const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const request = (text) => {
    console.log("пошол зарос на сервер");
  };

  const debaunce = (fn, timeoutMs) => {
    return function perform(...args) {
      const previousCall = this.lastCall;
      this.lastCall = Date.now();
console.log(this)
      if (previousCall && this.lastCall - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
        clearTimeout(this.lastCallTimer);
      }
      this.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeoutMs)
    };
  };

  const debaunceRequest = debaunce(request, 1000);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
    debaunceRequest(value);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper1">
        <div className="wrapper2">
            <input
              placeholder="введи текст"
              onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}
              className="inputField field"
              value={text}
            />
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  );
};
```

Функция debaunce организует ту самую задержку. Но в codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-buck-wjhbys?file=/src/App.js:58-1065

this ссылается на объект window и поэтому все работает. Но в реальном проекте мне кажется использовать Window в таких целях не правильно.
Пробовал написать так:

```
const debaunce = <T extends never>(fn: T, timeoutMs: number) =>
  function perform(...args) {
    let lastCall = null;
    let lastCallTimer: any = null;
    const previousCall = lastCall;
    console.log(lastCall, lastCallTimer);
    lastCall = Date.now();

    if (previousCall && lastCall - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
      clearTimeout(lastCallTimer);
    }
    lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeoutMs);
  };
```

Но в таком случае переменным lastCallTimer и lastCall значения не присваиваются.
Подскажите прав ли я по поводу использования window в проекте? Почему не идёт присвоение значений в переменные.
Оговорюсь что я знаю про множество других решений с задержкой времени. И с признательностью рассмотрю предложенные варианты. Но всё таки хочется разобраться с этим примером.
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: `Почему не идёт присвоение значений в переменные` так ты каждый раз создаешь новые функции. Они "не помнят" ничего про "старые" функции и их значения.

Comment: Получается без хранения значения переменных в Window не обойтись в данном примере?

Comment: Я бы вообще назвал этот пример неудачным... Как вариант, `useRef`-ом создать объект и его использовать вместо `windiw`.

Comment: Еще хотел заметить - в случае размонтирования элемента у тебя таймер некому удалять. Такое может привести к ошибкам Реакта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите прав ли я по поводу использования window в проекте?

Думаю что по возможности этого нужно избегать.

> Почему не идёт присвоение значений в переменные.

Присвоение "идет"... Но в твоем варианте нет ничего постоянного, все переопределяется при рендере. Кроме `window`.

> Но всё таки хочется разобраться с этим примером.

Как вариант, можно `useRef`-ом создать "постоянный" объект (аналог `window`) и в нем хранить твои переменные.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const obj = React.useRef({});

  const request = (text) => {
    console.log("пошол зарос на сервер");
  };

  const debaunce = (fn, timeoutMs) => {
    return function perform(...args) {
      const previousCall = obj.current.lastCall;
      obj.current.lastCall = Date.now();
      if (previousCall && obj.current.lastCall - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
        clearTimeout(obj.current.lastCallTimer);
      }
      obj.current.lastCallTimer = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeoutMs)
    };
  };

  const debaunceRequest = debaunce(request, 1000);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
    debaunceRequest(value);
  };


  return (
    <div className="wrapper1">
      <div className="wrapper2">
          <input
            placeholder="введи текст"
            onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}
            className="inputField field"
            value={text}
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

> Оговорюсь что я знаю про множество других решений с задержкой времени. И с признательностью рассмотрю предложенные варианты.

Вот такой вариант можно использовать...

```js
const request = (text) => {
  console.log("пошол зарос на сервер");
};


const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(_ => {
  if (text === null) return
    const v = setTimeout(request, 1000)
    return _ => clearTimeout(v)
  }, [text])

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setText(value);
  };


  return (
    <div className="wrapper1">
      <div className="wrapper2">
          <input
            placeholder="введи текст"
            onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}
            className="inputField field"
            value={text || ''}
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за ответы. Я написал hook с использованием useRef. Получилось так:

```
function useDebounce(fn: any, timeoutMs: number): Function {
  // в ссылках хранится id таймера и время предидущего вызова функции
  const lastCallTimerRef = useRef<number | null>(null);
  const lastCallRef = useRef<number | null>(null);

  return function perform(...args: Array<any>) {
    // при повторном вызове функции текущее время прошлого вызова становится прошлым временем для текущего вызова
    const previousCall = lastCallRef.current;
    lastCallRef.current = Date.now();

    if (previousCall && lastCallRef.current - previousCall <= timeoutMs) {
      clearTimeout(lastCallTimerRef.current as number);
    }
    lastCallTimerRef.current = window.setTimeout(() => fn(...args), timeoutMs);
  };
}
```